# Trigger O365PostMessageBuild only when the pipeline is runned by schedule

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the follwing schedule in the pipeline

```
schedules:
  - cron: "0 0 * * *"
    displayName: Daily midnight build
    branches:
      include:
        - main
```

I use this to send notification

```
  - task: O365PostMessageBuild@0
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      addressType: 'url'
      url: 'https://webhook.office.com/webhookb2/9615602a-d293-4469-ba56'
      messageType: 'message'
      title: 'Test Result'
      summary: 'Scheduled nightly test run'
      text: 'Branch : main'
      includeLink: true
      linkText: 'View last run'
```

I want the task to be executed only when the pipeline is triggered. How could I achieve that.

Comment: You mean not by the cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to schedule task for other triggers than cron you need to add condition to the task:

```yaml
  - task: O365PostMessageBuild@0
    condition: and(succeededOrFailed(), (variables['Build.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
    inputs:
      addressType: 'url'
      url: 'https://webhook.office.com/webhookb2/9615602a-d293-4469-ba56'
      messageType: 'message'
      title: 'Test Result'
      summary: 'Scheduled nightly test run'
      text: 'Branch : main'
      includeLink: true
      linkText: 'View last run'
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you have list of all possible values:

> The event that caused the build to run.

```
Manual: A user manually queued the build.
IndividualCI: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in.
BatchedCI: Continuous integration (CI) triggered by a Git push or a TFVC check-in, and the Batch changes was selected.
Schedule: Scheduled trigger.
ValidateShelveset: A user manually queued the build of a specific TFVC shelveset.
CheckInShelveset: Gated check-in trigger.
PullRequest: The build was triggered by a Git branch policy that requires a build.
ResourceTrigger: The build was triggered by a resource trigger or it was triggered by another build.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the task to be executed only when the pipeline is triggered. How could I achieve that.

It seems you want the task to be executed only when there have been source code changes, which trigger the pipeline.

To achieve this, you could add the argument `always: boolean` to this task:

```
schedules:
- cron: string # cron syntax defining a schedule
  displayName: string # friendly name given to a specific schedule
  branches:
    include: [ string ] # which branches the schedule applies to
    exclude: [ string ] # which branches to exclude from the schedule
  always: boolean # whether to always run the pipeline or only if there have been source code changes since the last successful scheduled run. The default is false.
```

Please check the document [Scheduled triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers) for some more details.